# How to make vibration in WebGL

Tags: unity-webgl

I need vibrate phone in webgl builds. It would be cool if you could adjust the duration and intensity. However, I don't even know how to make even a normal vibration.

I tried use this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/177384/vibration-duration-for-mobile-devices-in-unity
but it doesn't work, and on the internet i have found only asset for 30$ so i will be glad of any help

Answer (score 0):

[**Vibration API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) can be used, but at the time of answer, some devices (with Safari mostly) doesn't support it.

Unity script:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class Vibration : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Vibrate(int ms);
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
            Vibrate(1000);
#else
            Debug.Log("Simulate vibration");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

JS code (in Assets/Plugin/WebGL/Vibration.jslib):

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library,
{
    Vibrate: function(duration)
    {
        if (typeof navigator.vibrate === "function") {
            navigator.vibrate(duration);
        }
    }
});
```